# NAN values when I try to compute percent and put into new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

```
#Get CSV
csv_path = "Resources/election_data_test.csv"
poll_df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, encoding="utf-8")
#Print to view it
print("polldf", poll_df.head())
#Group by Candidate count uniques
group_df = poll_df.groupby("Candidate")['Voter ID'].nunique()
#check that the right values are resulted
print(group_df)
#put in new dataframe with column "Votes"
vote_df = pd.DataFrame({"Votes":group_df})
#get the sum of all votes
sum_df = vote_df.sum()
#Putin new dataframe and compute %
pct_df=pd.DataFrame({"Votes": group_df, "pct":group_df/sum_df})
print("votes",vote_df.head())
print("sum",sum_df.head())
print("pct",pct_df.head())
```

[image: Output]

What I want is
Candidate Votes %Votes

Comment: Check the indexes of the things you are "joining" by putting them both in a dataframe.

Comment: I am so new to Python and Pandas I am not sure I know what that means.

Comment: Use the IPython REPL for dev and debug. If you do a `df.head(10).to_dict()` you probably have smaller things you can copy paste and people can reproduce it here.

Comment: But if you look at group_df and sum_df they are different things with different indices.

Comment: .index for example.

Comment: But make sure you are in the IPython REPL. Do this:

ipython

>>> import myfile as m;

Comment: Then m.<TAB> ... and just keep dot tabbing and mashing at things. You will iterate much faster seeing the options that show up for you.

Comment: I don't know why it worked but when I merged on candidate, I got the output I wanted.
sum_df = vote_df.sum()
#Put in new dataframe and compute %
pct = round(100* vote_df / sum_df,2)
pct_df = pd.merge(vote_df,pct, on="Candidate") -- mathtick, I think your suggestion about indexes kind of lead me in the right direction.